# using setattr within a class method to sel something on self

Tags: python, class, setattr

When doing this

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            getattr(self, key)
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

.. the update function won't update an instance of this class.  I've tried `self.__setattr__(key, value)` and `object.__setattr__(self, key, value)` and even tried `eval(f"self.{key}={repr(value)}")` which threw an error!

UPDATE: The code does work.initially I had coded `self.__setattr__(key, value)`.  Microsoft vscode ( running on linux ) somehow caches things, for a very very long time and despite rotating through several changes of code didn't show any change in the test results i was running.  After taking a break to ask this question I ran the answer code below, then reverted to setattr and everything worked from there.  really annoyed with that!!

Comment: You don't need `getattr` (it will throw if attribute you're trying to set is neither `a` nor `b`), but your code works. `e = Example(1, 2); e.update(a=10); print(e.a)` prints 10.

Comment: It works for me!
```ex = Example(3, 4)
ex.update(a=5)

print(ex.a)
Output:
5```
How do you try your code?

Comment: `update` is probably too general anyway. Do you intend to allow it to create new attributes in addition to `a` and `b`?

Comment: I only want existing attributes to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__dict__` as a shortcut:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        # you need to do some checks here (if attribute exists or not)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


e = Example(1, 2)
print(e.__dict__)

e.update(a=3, b=4)
print(e.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```